# German bibliography in Overleaf with plainnat style

Tags: bibtex, natbib, overleaf, german

I wanted to switch my bibliography from `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to a style, that does not give me **and** instead of **und** between the autors.

I tried `\usepackage{bibgerm}` and `\bibliographystyle{gerplain}` together with `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`, but this does give me *(17)* instead of *(Author et al., 2017)* citation. And also `\citeauthor` does not work anymore.

I just tried giving `\usepackage[style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear ,sorting=ytn]{biblatex}` but this recognizes none of my citations.

I am using Overleaf so I haven't found a way to simply edit the plainnat.bst. My bib file is generated by

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ma.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `biblatex`, the syntax is different: did you use `\addbidresource{ma.bib}` in your preamble, and `\printbibliography` at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows in order to create a suitably modified version of `plainnat.bst`.

- If you can't locate the file Overleaf's TeX distribution, you can copy it from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst.
- Rename the copy and call it, say, `plainnat-und.bst`. You're obviously free to choose a different file name -- as long as the filename extension is `.bst`.
- Open the file `plainnat-und.bst` is a text editor.
- Replace all three instances of the string `" and "` with `" und "` -- one each in the functions `format.names`, `format.full.names` and `format.lab.names`.
- Save the file `plainnat-und.bst` in the folder where your main tex file is located.
- In the main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-und}` and perform a full recompile cycle in order to fully propagate all changes.

---

*Addendum*: Here's a complete MWE (minimum working example) and its output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab:3001, author = "A and B", title = "Gedanken", year = 3001}
@misc{cde:3002, author = "C and D and E", title = "Gedanken", year = 3002}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-und}

\begin{document}
\citet{ab:3001}

\citet{cde:3002}, \citep{cde:3002}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. It was pretty easy to edit the month names, and pages to Seiten the same way.

Comment: @Leon D does one of you guys know how to change the field edition to "Auflage"? tried it using the same method as above.. but it didnt work

Comment: Another comment: I trust the code makes it obvious how to go about changing the conjunction word for languages other than German. E.g., if your document is in Italian, the fourth bullet point in the list given above would become "Replace all three instances of the string `" and "` with `" e "` -- one each in the functions `format.names`, `format.full.names` and `format.lab.names`."